# Improve performance in WPF with many UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml

I'm very new in WPF and I need some advise on how to create a view with many UIElements at the same time. What i want to do, is to view some kind of table with fixed width and height for each cell. In each cell could be a random number of textblocks with a different back and forecolor (see image).

[Image for table-like view with many UiElements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDlyG.png)

That is what I have done so far... I created an usercontrol for the content of one cell which binds the items in an itemcontrol.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding Backcolor, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBrushConverter}}" >
                <Viewbox MaxHeight="20" >
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Caption}"
                        Foreground="{Binding Forecolor, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBrushConverter}}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This usercontrol is also binded to an itemcontrol for representing the x-axis of my table.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:DayView DataContext="{Binding Days}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the same is done for the y-axis with an nice scrollviewer around. So, the problem is, that there are many many elements in the virtual tree. In my sample case there are over 60.000 elements listed in the tree. This results in a bad performance, when opening the view. The scrolling performance is quite okay, but he takes several seconds to open the view.

I've tried some things like the CacheMode and so on, but all of that doesnt effect the opening performance. Using a VirtualizingStackPanel results in bad scrolling performance. I even cant figure out what takes so long to build up the Ui. Seems that he need a lot of time to measure all UiElemtents, but Im not sure...

Are there tips to make such an UiElement rich view any faster? As I said, Im very new in WPF and that is only a performance test. We have such an Ui in Winforms, but there, the whole table was user painted. In WPF it is so easy to rebuild the Winforms design with stock content-controls that I only want to draw all for myself as a last resort.

Comment: What you want is "virtualization": You want the UI to create only the controls that are currently scrolled into view. There's a [`VirtualizingStackpanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that does that. There isn't a virtualizing UniformGrid. If you can't find a control that virtualizes what you've got, you might look at rigging up a vertical VirtualizingStackPanel containing a large number of horizontal VirtualizingStackPanels. Hardly ideal, but it might be the least hassle.

Comment: My guess is that it is actually the layout step that is taking the most time instantiating the view, since it is only the initial opening of the view that is slow for you (you mention that scrolling performance is good).  In that case, virtualization will probably not help you much.  I think the only way to speed up the layout step is going to be to use fixed height and widths.  With this many controls though, I'm not sure how much performance you will ever be able to get out of it.

Comment: I tried this with your UniformGrid, tried pulling out the converter, tried fixed height and width, etc. -- not sure if it bought me anything at all. Definitely still too slow to release. Then I tried replacing the UniformGrid with VirtualizingStackPanel (and commenting out the whole ItemsPanel, too). It started *instantly*, with the same collection.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Thanks for the fast answer. Is it possible to send me some code of how you did that? How can I remove the whole ItemsPanel, because I can't set an ItemSource for the VirtualizingStackPanel. As a beginner, its quite confusing, because there are so many places, where I can turn on virtualization. Starting with WPF feels like Im never using any programming language at all.

Comment: I meant just comment out your ItemsControl.ItemsPanel thing, or replace UniformGrid within it with VirtualizingStackPanel. Unfortunately all that does is demonstrate that virtualization solves the performance issue, because VSPanel gives you a single row or column. To nest them for an ersatz grid... Gets ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here for a possible solution to your problem by using virtualization:

[WPF Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization)

Also if you want to go another way, there are commercial 3rd party WPF control libraries that handle virtualization with various degrees of success. To name a few: Xceed, Syncfusion, DevExpress and Telerik.

> I even cant figure out what takes so long to build up the Ui.

Hoping you are using VS2015 (or something better), there are a few ways to get an answer to what is taking so long. Visual Studio has a live visual tree tool (Debug->Windows) where you can see the visual tree in real time and it might help you find and eliminate some of the UI elements you don't really need (like borders inside more borders, etc)

Second, you can run the Diagnostic tools (Alt+F2), choose CPU usage and that should generate a report where you can see where your program is spending the most time. Hopefully this will isolate the issue to certain methods that can be optimized afterwards.

Also, more detail about your problem would be welcome. What is the code that populates the ItemsSource do exactly?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem that virtualization can solve.  He mentions that scrolling performance is good, it is only the initial opening of the view that is slow.  That suggests to me that it is the layout step of the visual tree is the main bottleneck.  If scrolling performance was bad, then I would agree with you about using virtualization.

Comment: @Dragos: Thanks for your reply. It's not like I haven't tried virtualization. But unfortunately it seems that I'm doing something wrong or do it at the wrong place in my UI Code. My first attempt of virtualization was, that it opens slow, with 60000 items in the visual tree, and as I scrolled to the last item, the visual tree reduces to ~2000 items which should happen in the first place. I will read the article about virtualization, thanks for the link.

Comment: So if ~60k objects are downsized to 2k there must be a great amount of garbage collection happening which can slow down the app significantly, You can use commercial apps like dotMemory to see what objects are being allocated and collected. Apart from that also keep in mind that WPF has one rendering thread (and one UI thread) see here for a complete read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx

Also see this for optimizing controls in visual tree: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx